# How to return back to paused Activity which is launched the browser, from a link in webpage?

Tags: android, uri, lifecycle, intentfilter

i am developing an online shop application. i want to direct user to a payment page using browser. when user paid the price server direct user to a another webpage. in that webpage click on a link and return to app also get the payment result from the link.

when user want's to pay i use a intent to direct user to web browser like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("payment-link"));
startActivity(intent);
```

then i used `"<a href="">"` tag to return to activity which lunched the browser like this:

in html:

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=my-package-name;category=android.intent.category.DEFAULT;category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;S.status=ok;end">Go back to App</a>
```

in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.TestActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="my-package-name" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

but the result is not what i want. i want to resume the activity not create one on top of browser stack. i also used `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` but onBackPressed direct to activity and i know it is what's expected.

i want this:
[image]

is it any way to resume activity or any other suggestion to implement this scenario? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it. browser should be launched with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` and "MyActivity" should be singleTask.

in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.OrderDetailsActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ir.bornait.isan" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

for launching browser:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("payment-link"));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(intent);
```